# Select item by hidden column value

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, lookup

I have one `LookUpEdit` control in my form and this `LUE` have three columns (`ID` for `ValueMemeber`, `Description` for `DisplayMember` and `Name` that is the hidden column) in some point I need to select the row/item with the specific value from the hidden column `Name` I can't use `KeyValue` or `DisplayText` because that column is not related to this properties.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? You can still reference and get values from hidden columns.

Comment: I need to select by code the row from my `LUE` where the hidden column `Name` value  be the same that a specific value I choose.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LoopUpEdit, but can you get the selected row index and then access the value by using the ´SelectedRowIndex´ and your ´ColumnIndex´?

Comment: @AugustoQ I can use `LookUpEdit1.GetColumnValue("FieldName")` to get the value from the column in the selected row, but I need to select a row using one value as reference.

Comment: So, find the row by searching all rows where a cell has a certain value?

Comment: Yes @David and select that row

Comment: I've never used a `LookUpEdit` before but is there some sort of iteration you could use? `For Each row as LookupEditRow in myLUE.Rows`?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I use `lue.EditValue = lue.Properties.GetDataSourceRowIndex("FieldName", "Value")` the problem is solve.